# Plot solutions of ODE with discontinuous source

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the ODE
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \Phi(t,x) = H(\Phi(t,x)), & t>0, x \in \mathbb{R} \\
\Phi(0,x) = x, & x \in \mathbb R,
\end{cases}
$$
where $H$ is the heaviside function. How can I compute the solution $\Phi$ and how can I plot it using Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a simplification of the problem: make $x$ a discrete variable with a finite domain.  For example: $x \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$.

Then for each $t$, the function $\Phi(t, x)$ becomes a vector with coordinates indexed by $x$:
$$
\phi(t) = \left( \phi_{-1}(t), \; \phi_{0}(t), \; \phi_{1}(t), \; \phi_{2}(t) \right)
$$
Now your ODE can be considered for each coordinate.  For example, for $x = -1$ we have:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\dot{\phi}_{-1}(t) & = & H( \phi_{-1}(t) ),\\
\phi_{-1}(0) & = & -1.
\end{array}
$$
Thus,
$$
\dot{\phi}_{-1}(0) = H( -1) = 0.
$$

And so on.